# Why is JSPM not bundling the dependencies of the bundled module?

Tags: jspm

I'm trying to bundle my app like
`jspm bundle myapp/index.jsx --dev` for development where my `index.jsx` has some imports..

```
import React from 'react'
import { store } from './store'
...
```

When I actually navigate to my application I can clearly see in the network tab that my reducers that are presently being imported inside of `store.js` are being loaded separately instead of as part of the `build.js` bundle produced.

Do I need to use bundling arithmetic to explicitly include these dependencies inside of my store? I thought the bundling was supposed to go through all the dependencies inside the module, bundling them inclusively?

Comment: Explicitly adding my store to the bundle task like `jspm bundle myapp/index.jsx + myapp/store.js` fixes my problem but the question still stands of why is it not actually automatically including dependencies in the bundle? Do imports at the top of the module not actually count towards the bundled deps?

Comment: To prove another point, if I tried adding a non-existent import, like `import nothing from './doesnotexist.jsx'` it errors when attempting to bundle implying it does navigate these.